# Hardware "back" button doesn't work after typing in edittext

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my form fragment Hardware "back" button work not correctly. For example when I opened fragment and when I didn't start typing, and I pressed Hardware "back" button it's work excellent. But when I started typing and after typing press to Hardware "back" button app crashed without any error logs.

my form fragment

```
public class D_Category_Login extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    public static FragmentListItemClick fragmentListItemClick;
    EditText edt_name,edt_lastname,edt_phone,edt_pass1,edt_pass2;
    String name="";
    DBHelper dbHelper;

    public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://admin.unimax.kz/api/Klientapi/AddClient?";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "first_name";
    public static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "last_name";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_login, null);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Регистрация");
         edt_name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_firstname);
         edt_lastname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        edt_phone = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.login);
        edt_pass1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pass);
        edt_pass2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pass_repeet);
        Button btn_submit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        TextView tv_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);

        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_number.setOnClickListener(this);


        edt_phone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
//                 TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(!s.toString().contains("+7 ")){
                    edt_phone.setText("+7 ");
                    Selection.setSelection(edt_phone.getText(), edt_phone.getText().length());

                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    void setfragmentclick(FragmentListItemClick fr){
        fragmentListItemClick = fr;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_submit:{
                if (edt_name.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() || edt_lastname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    if (edt_name.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                        edt_name.setError("Заполните это поле");
                        requestFocus(edt_name);
                    }
                    if (edt_lastname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                        edt_lastname.setError("Заполните это поле");
                        requestFocus(edt_lastname);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    CheckInternet();

                }
            }
            break;
            case R.id.tv_number:{
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "+77079300066"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    void CheckInternet(){
        if (isOnline()){
            registerUser();

        }
        else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Проверьте подключение к Интернету");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Закрыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
    void registerUser(){
        final String first_name = edt_name.getText().toString().trim();
        final String last_name = edt_lastname.getText().toString().trim();
        String fill_url = REGISTER_URL+"familia="+Uri.encode(last_name)+"&name="+Uri.encode(first_name);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, fill_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
                        final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                        final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        name+= String.valueOf(edt_name.getText()+" "+String.valueOf(edt_lastname.getText()));
                        cv.put("id_user", Integer.valueOf(response));
                        cv.put("name", name);
                        db.execSQL("delete from form_login");
                        db.insert("form_login",null, cv);
                        db.close();
                        dbHelper.close();
                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Ошибка сервера"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

My form fragment is child fragment. And this parent fragment where I implement backaction.

```
  @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            getView().requestFocus();
            getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        backAction();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

public  void backAction() {

        if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

        else  {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(0, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `TextWatcher` like

```
TextWatcher textWatcher=new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!s.toString().contains("+7 ")){
                edt_phone.setText("+7 ");
                Selection.setSelection(edt_phone.getText(), edt_phone.getText().length());

   }
};
```

Add it to `edt_phone` like

```
edt_phone.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Then in the back press event remove the listener,

```
getView().setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        edt_phone.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                    return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your foam fragment(child fragment)

```
Communicator communicator;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();
communicator.exitFragment();
}

public void setCommunicator(Communicator communicator)
{
 this.communicator = communicator;
 }

public interface Communicator 
{
void exitFragment();
}
```

in your parent fragment do this

```
public parentFragment extends Fragment implements childFragment.Communicator
{

@override
public void onCreatView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
childFragment.setCommunicator(this);
}

public void exitFragment()
  {
getActivity().finish();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are managed by the Fragment Managers which are called by the Activity; so, to control what you want to do when the back button is clicked, you must do that in the activity;

Now, if you have more than one fragment set, you should use tags to find them, check to see if they are visible and if so, do what you mentioned above.

When setting your fragments, you should give them a tag and then use this tag later to findFragmentByTagName() and do an if check to see which fragment is set at the moment;

Let me know if you need any clarification on the same.